# LINQ to XML's select is not working

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a xml and I am using LINQ to XML to retrieve data from XML file.

following is my LINQ code

```
XElement newCustOrd = new XElement("ad",
from c in custOrd.Element("ad").Elements("adinfo")
where ((string)c.Attribute("title")).Contains("Android")
select new XElement("adinfo",
    new XElement("title", (string)c.Attribute("title")),
    new XElement("phone", (string)c.Attribute("phone")),
    new XElement("email", (string)c.Attribute("email"))
)
);
```

The problem my select statement in the query is only retrieving first element in XML file.

the element whose title contains `Android` is element number 4.

Any help will be appreciated

Following is my XML file's content

```
<ads>
 <ad id="bcc0d6dd-75c6-4e18-8318-a9defc8c0216" date="4/16/2016 4:00:16 AM">
   <adinfo title="Wanted: iPod 5" email="message4fahad@yahoo.com" phone="7803051822" rod="" rprice="Please contact" rat="Wanted" cdetails="" address="5204 52 Ave, Rocky Mountain House, AB T4T 1G8" postal="T4T 1G8" description="Wanted: iPod 5" />
    <adimg>
     <img main="T" src="fede4afa-9f62-4cb5-a215-9e8714247416.jpg" />
     <img main="F" src="" />
</adimg>
</ad>
 <ad id="8482fcb2-8fb0-4e7e-9b51-4ed77ac3cd5f" date="4/6/2016 1:12:44 AM">
   <adinfo title="Sharp 50&quot; TV, LC-50LB261U, little over a year old" email="message4fahad@yahoo.com" phone="7802391211" rod="" rprice="475" rat="Offering" cdetails="" address="   Edmonton, AB T5T6J9" postal="T5T6J9" description="Sharp 50&quot; TV, LC-50LB261U, little over a year old" />
 <adimg>
    <img main="T" src="2108fcd5-1074-4bbe-9d66-a69fe6b4216f.jpg" />
    <img main="F" src="" />
</adimg>
</ad>
<ad id="4b6d750d-2bd9-4382-8a45-c580f94c23ad" date="3/30/2016 1:31:26 AM">
  <adinfo title="BEST GIFT!! FREE TV AND MOVIES FOREVER!! - FREE KEYBOARD!!" email="message4fahad@yahoo.com" phone="780-293-8574" rod="" rprice="149" rat="Offering" cdetails="" address="4817 118 Ave NW, Edmonton, AB T5W 1B5" postal="T5W 1B5" description="BEST GIFT!! FREE TV AND MOVIES FOREVER!! - FREE KEYBOARD!!" />
 <adimg>
   <img main="T" src="0c79e71f-382c-4e69-83b5-c6ce27044fb7.jpg" />
   <img main="F" src="" />
 </adimg>
</ad>
<ad id="aad706c0-1722-457e-bbb4-58b5abe1145e" date="3/18/2016 12:59:50 AM">
 <adinfo title="Android TV Boxes Are Better! Credit Cards Accepted." email="message4fahad@yahoo.com" phone="780-887-8978" rod="" rprice="119.99" rat="Offering" cdetails="" address="   Strathcona County, AB T8H2G8" postal="T8H2G8" description="Android TV Boxes Are Better! Credit Cards Accepted." />
  <adimg>
    <img main="T" src="de5cc90a-6e47-4bed-81a1-eec8945f4495.jpg" />
    <img main="F" src="" />
 </adimg>
</ad>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Elements()` instead of singular `Element()` in `custOrd.Element("ad")` if you meant to get *all* `<ad>` elements instead of only the first.